# Running an azure cloud service after every n days

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services, azure-blob-storage

I have created an azure service which is responsible for below task:
(1) Access the blob containers and download the files from there.
(2) Extract some data from downloaded files
(3) Stored the extracted data to an Azure SQL Server

I want to run this processing after every 7 days. Is there a way to achieve this? or can I use any other option than cloud service to achieve the above goal?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you to use **Azure Function** as its **Timer-based processing** (**Timer trigger**) feature is able to fulfill your requirements.

> Timer triggers call functions based on a schedule, one time or
>   recurring.

Reference: [Azure Functions timer trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer), [Azure Functions Pricing](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/functions/)

Another great advantage of using Azure Function for your scenario is its pricing model.

> Azure Functions consumption plan is billed based on resource
>   consumption and executions. 
>   Consumption plan pricing includes a
>   monthly free grant of 1 million requests and 400,000 GB-s of resource
>   consumption per month.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly not natively with the Cloud Service itself. I mean, you can obviously code it so it performs some task(s) and sleeps for 7 days, but you will pay for all of that time, that makes no sense

You can use Azure WebJobs, Functions and Scheduler for this purpose, or you can create a PowerShell\Cli or something else cron task\task scheduler to turn on your Azure Cloud Service, wait for it to finish processing and turn it off. But that seems like a lot of extra effort, I'd rather go with Scheduler or Functions.